# Python Folium: how to create a folium.map.Marker() with multiple popup text lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, maps, folium

Is there an possibility to create a second or third line for the popup text including adjustment of the width and height of the popup box?

Found something on GitHub, but is that the only way? 
https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/294

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put html code inside a popup by means of [`IFrame`](https://python-visualization.github.io/branca/element.html#branca.element.IFrame):

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[43.775, 11.254],
               zoom_start=5)

html = '''1st line<br>
2nd line<br>
3rd line'''

iframe = folium.IFrame(html,
                       width=100,
                       height=100)

popup = folium.Popup(iframe,
                     max_width=100)

marker = folium.Marker([43.775, 11.254],
                       popup=popup).add_to(m)
m
```

and you get:

[image]